# Matching ids to countries in pandas or dask

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# initialize list of lists
data = [[2, [4], "['RU']"], [4, [9,18,24], "['US' 'CN']"], [6, [],  "['']"],[7, [2],  "['DE' 'IT']"],[9, [4],  "['US']"],[14, [18,6],  "['SA']"],[18, [17],  "['GB' 'KR']"]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_docdb','country'])
```

As you can see, the column 'country' includes the countries related to the ids contained in the column 'docdb' which, often appear also in the column 'country' as well (e.g. 17 cited by docdb 18 and 24 cited by docdb 4 do not appear among the docdb). Now, my aim is to obtain a list of countries related to the ids within the column 'cited_docdb' whereby they appear in the column docdb. The code should take into account that my original database is much larger than this toy example.
Specifically, I would like to obtain the following:

```
#initialize list of lists
data_result = [[2, [4], "['RU']", "['US' 'CN']"], [4, [9,18,24], "['US' 'CN']","['US','GB' 'KR','']"], [6, [],  "['']", "['']"],[7, [2],  "['DE' 'IT']", "['']"],[9, [4],  "['US']", "['US' 'CN']"],[14, [18,6],  "['SA']", "['GB' 'KR', 'US' 'CN']"],[18, [17],  "['GB' 'KR']","['']"]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data_result, columns=['docdb', 'cited_docdb','country', 'desired'])
```

So the desired column contains the country(ies) related to each cited id in the column cited_docdb (if they appear in docddb).

Thank you

EDIT: currently my idea is to apply a BFS though I am not sure on how to do it in order to avoid increasing complexity. I started by inverting the df and am currently building the BFFS algorithm:

```
exploded_data=df.explode(['cited_docdb'])

inverting_db_prova = {}
keys_d0 = set()


for index, row in exploded_data.iterrows():
    i = row['cited_docdb']
    j=row['docdb']
    if row['desired'] == "":
        keys_d0.add(j)
    if str(i) != 'nan':
        if i not in inverting_db_prova:
            inverting_db_prova[i] = [j]
        else:
            inverting_db_prova[i].append(j)
```

Comment: Do you have to use strings? This makes everything more complicated… Also this is not the first time you ask such a question, what is your current attempt?

Comment: @mozway Hi, so no I do not have to se strings but I would prefer to. Concerning my attempt, I would like to see how many times a country cites itself, meaning how many times in country appears the same 'country' as in 'desired' for each country.

Comment: I mean how many times in the variable 'country' appears the same country as in the variable 'desired'.

Comment: I meant "attempt" (i.e. what **you** tried to code), not "expectation" (what you want as a result) ;)

Comment: Please, see the edit above though it's not much